# RLIMIT_NPROC is exceeded every night at 0:00

Tags: error

I'm getting following error, every night at 0:00 for like 20 minutes. Then the shop is back again. All other things on the server are running smothely, so I think it is an Magento Problem.

```
Error in line 838

cannot fork, most likely the process limit RLIMIT_NPROC is exceeded
```

What I've done so far is deactivated all cronjobs. The Mistakes keeps popping up. There is nothing to find in the php error logs.

I need hints how to analyse the problem or best - to get rid of it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: May it be an apache problem? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19455681/2375207

Comment: I don't think so. The limit is at 32, that should be enough for Magento. Other installations are running fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a vServer it may approach its resource limits. Check your server configuration or consider upgrading to another plan.

You can also use apache benchmark to verify your servers limits:

`ab -n 10000 -c 100 http://www.yourdomain.com`